# Is it possible to connect to localhost on my rpi with an ethernet cable between rpi and computer (without router)?

Tags: networking

I have a php script on my rpi which i can visit when my computer is on the same network as the rpi.

But, i want to connect a rpi directly to my computer with an ethernet cable and in the browser of my computer i would like to open the php page from the rpi by visiting http://193.168.1.1/index.php. Is this possible and how can i approach this?

Comment: Yes, you plug an ethernet cable in between the two.  This is a general network question and not specific to the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a Raspberry Pi with a wireless network interface. So you want to have a static IP in the spare wired port of the rpi.

First of all *193.168* is not the best network for trying this, because it doesn't belong to a private range. I will use 10.1.1 in the example, it is the one I use in my own setup.

Edit the file */etc/network/interfaces* of the rpi and change the *eth0* section like this:

```
# rpi /etc/network/interfaces
auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.1.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I assume the other PC is a linux too, add a similar section with another IP. Notice this one ends in **.2**

```
# PC /etc/network/interfaces
auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.1.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent. It works. The rpi was assigning itself an ip in the range 169.254. Could not understand why it would not connect. However, as suggested by you i set up one of the private networks (10.1.1) and the magic started happening. Thank you! On a windows machine I had to set the gateway as well (dns can be left blank). Do not forget to call `sudo ifup eth0` and `sudo ifdown eth0` to reload the interfaces.